# Combine three grayscale images into RGB with MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I have three grayscale images where each image represents a single channel from a RGB image of 16-bit resolution.  I would like to convert them to obtain one single RGB image.  I have tried `cat` and `ind2rgb` but it is not working.  Should we index our grayscale images before using `ind2rgb`?  Is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code you tried

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have three matrices `R`,`G`,`B` of type `int16`. If you try

```
RGB = cat(3,R,G,B);
imshow(RGB)
```

[IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html) will complain that: `RGB images must be uint8, uint16, single, or double.`. In fact if you check the documentation:

> A truecolor image can be uint8, uint16, single, or double. An indexed
>   image can be logical, uint8, single, or double. A grayscale image can
>   be logical, uint8, int16, uint16, single, or double. A binary image
>   must be of class logical.

So if you concatenate three `int16` grayscale images, and you want to use IMSHOW, you have to convert the resulting truecolor image to something it supports:

```
imshow( im2double(RGB) )
```